# Best way to track time on view in React-Native

Tags: parse-platform, react-native

I'm trying to keep track of how much time a user spends on a given view in a react native iOS app, and then send it to Parse as a custom analytics item. What's the best way to do this?

My initial thought was to track the start time and exit time in the code used to generate a each individual page, but I was hoping there would be a more elegant way. Basically what I'm after is the amount of time that each view spends on top of the navigator stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Navigator` will emit events for when the different routes will receive and lose focus which should be enough for you to determine how long they spend on each view. You might use it together with the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle function.

```
navigator.navigationContext.addListener('didfocus', event => {
  console.log('Currently focused route is', event.data.route);
});
```